# A definite integral over the unit sphere

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, definite-integrals

Is there a closed form for the following definite integral over the unit sphere?

$$I = \int_0^{\pi}d\theta \sin\theta \int_0^{2\pi}d\phi |x (\sin\theta\cos\phi)^2 +(1-x)(\sin\theta\sin\phi)^2 - (\cos\theta)^2| $$

where $x\in[0,2]$. This came up in a physics problem.

Mahthematica (surprisingly) returned the result $I = 4 \pi  \sqrt{\frac{x}{(x+1)^3}}$ which really only agrees with the numerical integration at $x=\frac{1}{2}$, so it is most likely wrong.

Since the function inside the absolute value signs is just a weighted sum of squares of the coordinates of the unit directional vector, I thought that it might be dealt with by going to some sort of ellipsoidal coordinate system. But so far I have not found a way to make it work.

**Update 1**:

Thanks to the comment from @SangchulLee , I was able to proceed a bit further to the following intermediate result. First, we substitute

$$u(\phi)=x\cos^2\phi+(1-x)\sin^2\phi$$

Then, the integral reduces to

$$ I = \int_0^{2\pi}d\phi\int_{-1}^1dt | (1-t^2) u(\phi) - t^2 | = \frac{2}{3} \int_0^{2\pi}d\phi \left[ 1-2u(\phi) + 4u(\phi)\sqrt{\frac{u(\phi)}{1+u(\phi)}}\Theta(u(\phi)) \right] $$

where $\Theta$ is the Heaviside theta function. The integral of the first two summands yields zero, so we obtain

$$ I = \frac{8}{3} \int_0^{2\pi}d\phi \sqrt{\frac{u(\phi)^3}{1+u(\phi)}}\Theta(u(\phi))$$

Thus, for some special values of $x=0,1,\frac{1}{2}$, the integral can be easily performed. However, I am not able to go further from here on.

Comment: I still haven't completely figured out the value of the integral, but here is a reduction: $$I=\frac{8}{3}\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}f(x\cos^2\phi+(1-x)\sin^2\phi)\,\mathrm{d}\phi,\qquad f(u)=1-2u+\frac{4u^2\mathbf{1}[u\geq 0]}{\sqrt{u+1}}.$$ This yields some special values such as $$I(0)=I(1)=\frac{16}{3},\qquad I(\tfrac{1}{2})=\frac{8 \pi}{3 \sqrt{3}}.$$

Comment: @SangchulLee This is extremely helpful, but I quickly ran it through Mathematica and got $I(\frac{1}{2})=\frac{4}{3} \sqrt{\frac{2}{3}} \pi$, $I(0)=\frac{32 K(-1)}{9}$, and $I(1)=\frac{16}{9} \sqrt{2} K\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)$ where $K$ is the complete elliptic integral of the first kind.

Comment: @SangchulLee Also, could you show or give me some hints at how you got the intermediate result?

Comment: @SangchulLee Thanks to your comment, I was able to proceed a bit further and updated the question. See if this result was also something you have got!

Answer (score 1):

**Long Comment.** Here is a way to simplify the integral as I illustrated in my comment.

First, write $ u = x \cos^2\phi + (1-x)\sin^2\phi $ for simplicity, and note that

\begin{align*}
I
&= \int_{0}^{\pi}\mathrm{d}\theta \, \sin\theta \int_{0}^{2\pi} \mathrm{d}\phi \, \left| u \sin^2\theta - \cos^2\theta \right| \\
&= 8 \int_{0}^{\pi/2} \mathrm{d}\phi \, \int_{0}^{\pi/2} \mathrm{d}\theta \, \sin\theta \left| u \sin^2\theta - \cos^2\theta \right|.
\end{align*}

We simplify $I$ by computing the inner integral explicitly. Indeed, by substituting $t = \tan^2\theta$, we get

\begin{align*}
&\int_{0}^{\pi/2} \mathrm{d}\theta \, \sin\theta \left| u \sin^2\theta - \cos^2\theta \right| \\
&= \int_{0}^{\infty} \mathrm{d}t \, \frac{\left| u t - 1 \right|}{2(1+t)^{5/2}} \\
&= \int_{0}^{\infty} \mathrm{d}t \, \frac{1 - ut}{2(1+t)^{5/2}} - 2 \biggl( \int_{1/u}^{\infty} \mathrm{d}t \, \frac{1 - St}{2(1+t)^{5/2}} \biggr) \mathbf{1}[ u > 0] \\
&= \frac{1}{3} f(u),
\end{align*}

where

$$ f(u) = 1 - 2u + \frac{4u^{3/2}}{\sqrt{u+1}}\mathbf{1}[u > 0]. $$

Plugging this back, we end up with

$$ I
= \frac{8}{3} \int_{0}^{\pi/2} \mathrm{d}\phi \, f(x \cos^2\phi + (1-x)\sin^2\phi). $$

Comment: Thanks again for the comment! But I do not think your final expression matches the values you gave above. For example, for $x=\frac{1}{2}$, $u=\frac{1}{2}$, and $f(u)=\frac{\sqrt{6}}{3}$, which gives $I=\frac{8\pi}{3\sqrt{6}}$ and is off by a factor of $\sqrt{2}$ from the result of your first comment. I also got somewhat similar result (see update) which however yields the same numerical values as the ones from your first comment for $x=0,1,\frac{1}{2}$.

Comment: @Hector, Ah, indeed I made a typo both in my comment and here. I used the correct formula to compute the values of $I$ in the back-of-the-envelope calculation while made typos twice when transcribing them here. :s Let me fix it.

Answer (score 0):

With the help of Mathematica, I was finally able to find a closed form, though I am not able to construct a proof of it. I will note down the result in the following in the hope that it will still be of some value to someone that comes across similar problems in the future.

We first note that the integrand is $\pi$-periodic and even in $\phi$, we get
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
 I(x)
 &= \frac{32}{3} \int_0^{\pi/2} d\phi \sqrt{\frac{u(\phi)^3}{1+u(\phi)}} \Theta(u(\phi)>0) \\
 &= \frac{8}{3} \int_{-1}^{1} dy \sqrt{\frac{[(2x-1)y+1]^3}{(1-y^2)[(2x-1)y+3]}} \Theta((2x-1)y+1)
\end{split}
\end{equation}
where we have substituted $y=\cos2\phi$. Using Mathematica, we find the last expression to be
\begin{equation}
 I(x)
 = \frac{16}{3} \sqrt{\frac{x}{2-x}} \Re\left( (x-1)  K\left(\frac{1-2x}{x(x-2)}\right) - (x-2)  E\left(\frac{1-2x}{x(x-2)}\right) \right)
\end{equation}
where $\Re$ denotes the real part, $K$ is the complete elliptic integral of the first kind, and $E$ is the complete elliptic integral of the second kind.

Some special values of $I(x)$ can be obtained without using the elliptic integrals. For $x=0$, we have
\begin{equation}
 I(0)
 = \frac{8}{3} \int_{-1}^1 dy \frac{1-y}{\sqrt{(y+1)(3-y)}}
 = \frac{4}{3} \int_0^4 du \frac{1}{\sqrt{u}}
 = \frac{16}{3}
\end{equation}
where we have made the substitution $u=(y+1)(3-y)$. Similarly, for $x=1$, we have
\begin{equation}
 I(1)
 = \frac{8}{3} \int_{-1}^1 dy \frac{y+1}{\sqrt{(1-y)(y+3)}}
 = \frac{4}{3} \int_0^4 du \frac{1}{\sqrt{u}}
 = \frac{16}{3}
\end{equation}
where we have made the substitution $u=(1-y)(y+3)$. Lastly, for $x=\frac{1}{2}$, we have
\begin{equation}
 I\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)
 = \frac{8}{3\sqrt{3}} \int_{-1}^1 dy \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-y^2}}
 = \frac{8\pi}{3\sqrt{3}}
\end{equation}